# Blur in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I blur a background or create a Blur Overlay in Jetpack Compose? There is no documentation or resources whatsoever addressing this topic. Simply said: I'm looking to implement something like [this](https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView) natively in Jetpack Compose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this Jetpack Compose blur process library, which supports all Android versions. I hope it works for you.

[Jetpack Compose Cloudy - blur process library](https://github.com/skydoves/Cloudy)

Comment: Note: It have a this issue [When navigate from one screen to another screen, the new screen show the previous screen as an image above the root view in the compose screen](https://github.com/skydoves/Cloudy/issues/6)

Answer (score 68):

This is [a feature that has been requested](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166927547) (implemented in Compose `1.1.0-alpha03` for android 12 and above only) and which you might want to star.
The idea would be to create a blur modifier that would look like this:

```
Modifier.blur(radius = 16.dp)
```

Comment: work only on android 12+

Comment: Doesn't apply to the composables underneath, thus not possible to create a blur overlay.
It allows only to blur content inside the composable with the modifier applied.

Answer (score 12):

In  **Jetpack Compose**:1.1.0-alpha03, you can use:

```
Modifier.blur(30.dp)
```

but is only supported on Android 12 and above. Attempts to use this Modifier on older Android versions will be ignored.

**Reference**: [Modifier.blur](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).blur(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.draw.BlurredEdgeTreatment))

Comment: This works for JetBrains Compose on Desktop (using Linux here) out of the box

Answer (score 7):

For earlier versions than API 31 you still can use RenderScript (deprecated) or RenderScript Intrinsics Replacement Toolkit.
For the first way:

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    LocalContext.current.resources,
    R.drawable.your_image
)
val rs = RenderScript.create(LocalContext.current)
val bitmapAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap)
ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, bitmapAlloc.element).apply {
    setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS)
    setInput(bitmapAlloc)
    forEach(bitmapAlloc)
}
bitmapAlloc.copyTo(bitmap)
rs.destroy()
```

For the second you have to add *renderscript-toolkit* module to your project (look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate#scripts)) and then use:

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    LocalContext.current.resources,
    R.drawable.your_image
).let { Toolkit.blur(it, BLUR_RADIUS) }
```

Finally you can show blurred bitmap like this:

```
Image(
    bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
    "some description"
)
```

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/x3rocode/xblur-compose/tree/main

I know what you want.

I made simple realtime compose blur. 
try this. 
[image: pic]

[image: xblur]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33570772)

Comment: Worth mentioning is that this solution relies on Android Graphics Shading Language (AGSL), which is introduced in Android 13 (or API 33, to be more specific). https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/agsl

Answer (score 1):

Simply use blue modifier function like below.

```
Image(
  painter = painterResource (R.drawable.my_image)
  modifier = Modifier
   blur (radiusX = 15.dp, radiusY = 15.dp)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the [Toolkit library](https://github.com/iZakirSheikh/toolkit/tree/dev), which contains a custom blur modifier that can blur the background behind any composable in real time. It works on any version of Android.

**Example**

```
OptIn(ExperimentalToolkitApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BlurTopBar() {
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text("Blur Top Bar") },
        modifier = Modifier
            .statusBarsPadding()
            .legacyBackgroundBlur(
                blurRadius = 25f, // the radius of the blur effect, in pixels
                blurAlpha = 0.4f // the alpha value of the blur effect, between 0 and 1
            )
            .background(Color.White.copy(0.7f)) // the background color of the top bar
            .noise(0.05f) // the noise level of the blur effect, between 0 and 1
    )
}
```

I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@iZakirSheikh/blurring-the-lines-how-to-achieve-a-glassmorphic-design-with-jetpack-compose-0225560c2d64) that shows how to use my library and how to create stunning glassmorphic designs for your Android apps.

You can read it here: [Blurring the Lines: How to Achieve a Glassmorphic Design with Jetpack Compose](https://medium.com/@iZakirSheikh/blurring-the-lines-how-to-achieve-a-glassmorphic-design-with-jetpack-compose-0225560c2d64).

I hope you find my library and [article](https://medium.com/@iZakirSheikh/blurring-the-lines-how-to-achieve-a-glassmorphic-design-with-jetpack-compose-0225560c2d64) helpful. If you have any feedback or suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .blur(10.dp)
    ){
        AsyncImage(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center).fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            model =
            "https://images.genius.com/225d6cb0fef34cc080a51fefb2384c8b.599x607x1.jpg",
            contentDescription = "",
        )
    }
    Column {//insert the rest of UI code here}
```

I was having the same problem, I tried this and it is working as Column part overlays on top of the Box. This should overlap on each other giving you a blurred background.
Let me know if I am making any mistake. Hope it helps!

EDIT: Unfortunately Modifier.blur() is not backward compatible, so it will only work for Android 12+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Haze](https://github.com/chrisbanes/haze) (A blurring modifier for Compose Multiplatform / Jetpack Compose)

[image]

The most basic usage would be something like:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // For Compose Multiplatform AND Jetpack Compose
    implementation("dev.chrisbanes.haze:haze:0.6.0")
}
```

---

```
val hazeState = remember { HazeState() }

Scaffold(
  topBar = {
    TopAppBar(
      // Need to make app bar transparent to see the content behind
      colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(Color.Transparent),
      modifier = Modifier
        .hazeChild(state = hazeState)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
      /* todo */
    }
  },
  bottomBar = {
    NavigationBar(
      containerColor = Color.Transparent,
      modifier = Modifier
        .hazeChild(state = hazeState)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
      /* todo */
    }
  },
) {
  LazyVerticalGrid(
    modifier = Modifier
      .haze(
        state = hazeState,
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
      ),
  ) {
    // todo
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to blur an image The 'Modifier.blur' is supported on Android 12 and above. I encountered problems (crashes) with some of the libraries mentioned earlier. After searching for various solutions, I ended up using this one, which works.
if you are looking to blur an image use this

```
implementation("com.github.skydoves:landscapist-transformation:2.1.6")
implementation("com.github.skydoves:landscapist-glide:2.3.2")
```

add these dependecies

use it like this

```
 GlideImage(
                modifier= Modifier
                    .padding(2.dp)
                    .width(64.dp)
                    .height(64.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
                imageModel = { imageUrl },
                component = rememberImageComponent {
                    +BlurTransformationPlugin(radius = 10) // between 0 to Int.MAX_VALUE.
                }
            )
```

This configuration applies a blur transformation with a radius of 10 to your image. Adjust the radius as needed within the valid range from 0 to Int.MAX_VALUE