# Blur Modifier in Jetpack Compose Doesn't Work in Preview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I'm trying to use the Modifier.blur feature of Jetpack Compose for a project for work and it seems to not do anything in the preview. I'm using it like this:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .blur(30.dp)) {
    // Screen content here
}
```

The screen content isn't blurred at all. I've even tried applying blur to the individual composables in the box and that also doesn't change the preview. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does it work when you use it on a device? IOW, is this purely a preview problem? If so, my guess is that it is simply a limitation of the preview engine.

Comment: As a temporal solution, I used an xml-based gradient and coil to show the Image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Modifier.blur()` works only on Android 12+ devices so you probably do not want to use it anyways since it will not work for almost all your users (at least at the time I am writing this that barely any devices run Android 12).

It's due to all blur-related features being added on Android 12+ and they are not backward compatible. So you always do need unofficial methods to implement blur if you do want it to work for devices running Android 11 or lower.

It not working on the preview can be due to this or might simply be a bug since Compose is still new. I could not find any reported bugs related to blur so if it's a bug, they are not aware of it. If you are sure it is a bug you should report it to [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:612128%20status:open#) so it can get fixed ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the **Modifier.blur** does not work in **preview** because it requires an actual device as preview does not run on an **activity** or something.

If you are interested in knowing how to **blur the background** of apps running on API 21 and up using the blur modifier, you can refer to this answer on Stack Overflow: [Blur Modifier in Jetpack Compose Doesn't Work in Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77810848/9046284).

Comment: If you think another question provides a solution, then flag/vote to close as duplicate. Do not post answers linking to other questions (or other answers).