# Jetpack compose how to blur text area and line it to the bottom of a card

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to place text at the bottom of a card and blur the text area with a translucent color.

This is what I have so far.

The design I am trying to achieve is this. (Collection Area with cards specific part)

[image]

Here's my code:

```
@Composable
fun CollectionCardArea(
    collection: Collection,
    cardWidth: Dp
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(cardWidth)
            .padding(start = 2.dp, end = 25.dp, bottom = 5.dp, top = 0.dp)
            .clickable { },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(6),
        elevation = 4.dp
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(
                    data = collection.image
                ),
                contentDescription = collection.name,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
        }
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(20.dp)
            .background(Color.Transparent)
        ) {
            Text(text = collection.name, color = Color.White)
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is I cannot find a way to align the text to the bottom of the screen.
Also, I cannot figure out how to blur the text area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, Card can't position its own child (when there are multiple children). So you need to use something like `Column`, `Row`, `Box`, or else inside the card itself. So instead having a tree like this

```
- Card
  - Box
    - Image
  - Box
    - Text
```

You can try it like this

```
- Card
  - Box
    - Box
      - Image
    - Box
      - Text
```

Second, as for the blur in Jetpack-Compose you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998819/blur-in-jetpack-compose). But the API itself is only available on Android 12 and up.